# How to wrap only words in spans php?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a text string mixed with html and need to separate words **only** and wrap them in spans.

String:

```
$string ='<div class="something">What </div> if it it is is same <div style="color:red;">same </div>';
```

desired output

```
<div class="something">
  <span class="splits split1">
    What
  </span>
</div>
<span class="splits split2">
  if
</span>
<span class="splits split3">
  it
</span>
<span class="splits split4">
  it
</span>
<span class="splits split5">
  is
</span>
<span class="splits split6">
  is
</span>
<span class="splits split7">
  same
</span>
<div style="color:red;">
  <span class="splits split8">
    same
  </span>
</div>
```

I tried everything I could think of, preg_replace with word boundary,  preg_match , str_replace, combos with explodes , loops and replace, but one way or another the output fails and brakes the html or it adds replacement where it should not be.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you forgot the one tool that's designed for this: DOM. once you have your individual html nodes extracted with dom, THEN you can work on the text nodes and convert them into html.

Comment: @MarcB you are right about it , it would be great if you had time to  show an  example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @MarcB said, here with DOM life is tastier but since question is tagged [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) this could be a workaround (not %100 guaranteed though):

```
</?\b[^<>]+>(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+
```

PHP:

```
preg_replace_callback('~</?\b[^<>]+>(*SKIP)(*F)|\w+~', function($matches) {
    static $counter = 0;
    return "<span class=\"splits split".(++$counter)."\">{$matches[0]}</span>";
}, $string);
```

[Live demo](https://3v4l.org/qUgbn)